# Get list of recent added/deployed smart contracts

Tags: ethereum, etherscan

Is there a way to retrieve the most recent added/deployed smart contracts to the ethereum chain?

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Regards,

JR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newly deployed contract addresses are not directly available through the node RPC API (and its wrappers such as `ethersjs` and `web3js`), but you can build a script that

1. Subscribes to newly published blocks
2. Loops through transaction receipts on the block
3. And searches for `contractAddress` property of the transaction receipt

The `contractAddress` property returns `null` if the transaction does not deploy a contract (most transactions) or an `address` if the transaction deploys a contract.

---

The above mentioned approach only retrieves contracts that were deployed directly - by sending a transaction with empty `to` field and `data` field containing the contract bytecode.

It does not retrieve contracts that were deployed using an internal transaction. For example it would not catch the following `Hello` contract deployment (that is deployed by executing the `deployHello()` function).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Hello {}

contract HelloFactory {
    event Deployed(address);

    function deployHello() external {
        // deploys a new instance of the `Hello` contract to a new address
        address deployedTo = address(
            new Hello()
        );
        emit Deployed(deployedTo);
    }
}
```

If you want to retrieve deployments of these contracts as well, then you'd need to [debug](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/ns-debug#debugtraceblock) **each** newly produced block and search for the `create` and `create2` opcodes (each of them deploys a new contract, they take different input arguments).

---

So overall, it's not a simple task but it's doable.

It's generally discouraged to recommend any specific 3rd party APIs and tools here at StackOverflow. But I'm guessing that there are already some existing services that do all of this on their backend, and are able to return the aggregated list of newly deployed contracts as a result.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. So the delay will basically be 18 seconds (time between blocks). This gives me enough input to start working on a script using web3.py (https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/query-ethereum-blockchain-with-python).

Comment: @JR_ Delay might be different on each network. Ethereum block time is currently ~12 seconds (https://etherscan.io/chart/blocktime), other EVM networks have different block times. E.g. ~3 sec on Binance Smart Chain, ~2 sec on Polygon, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of Petr Hejda I created the following Python code:

```
import sys
import time
from web3 import Web3


def connect():
    # infura API key
    API_KEY = "INFURA_API_KEY"

    # change endpoint to mainnet or ropsten or any other of your account
    url = f"https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{API_KEY}"

    w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(url))
    # res = w3.isConnected()
    # print(res)
    return w3

def get_latest_block(connection):
    return connection.eth.get_block('latest')

def get_latest_block_id(block_information):
    return block_information['number']

def search_new_contracts(connection, block_information):
    block_transactions = block_information['transactions']
    # print(block_transactions)

    for transaction in block_transactions:
        transaction_data = connection.eth.getTransaction(transaction)

        if transaction_data['to'] == "":
            print(f"Contract creation transaction:  {transaction_data}")

    print("Block searching done")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    current_block_number = sys.maxsize

    connection = connect()

    while True:

        latest_block = get_latest_block(connection)
        latest_block_id = get_latest_block_id(latest_block)

        if current_block_number is not latest_block_id:
            print(f'New block detected: {latest_block_id}')
            search_new_contracts(connection, latest_block)
            current_block_number = latest_block_id
```

Problem is that it is slow so I have to see if I can speed things up.